# Find the probability of success $P$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be the random variable that follows the binomial distribution with expectation $\Bbb E(X)=7$ and variance $\Bbb V(X)=6$. Find the probability of success $p$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Express $\mathbb{E}[X]$ in terms of $n$ and $p$, where $n,p$ are the parameters of the distribution

Then do the same thing for the variance.

What you now have is a system of $2$ equations on $2$ variables solving which, gives you the result

Answer (score 1):

- $E(X) = n p$
- $V(X) = n p (1-p) = E(X) (1-p)$
  $$\Rightarrow p = 1-\frac{V(X)}{E(X)}= 1- \frac{6}{7}= \frac{1}{7}$$